# AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer: change videoGravity animated

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my project I am using AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer and AVPlayerLayer. Bot of them have similar interface and videoGravity property.
When I change AVPlayerLayer videoGravity property video is re-sized immediately with animation effect. With AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer videoGravity nothing happen till I change device orientation and then video is re-sized without animation.

How to change videoGravity of AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer to behave similar to the AVPlayerLayer?

Comment: How did you solved it finally?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found is to reinitialize the AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer for example:

```
var displayBufferLayer: AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer?
...
func reinitBufferLayer(videoGravity: AVLayerVideoGravity) {
    displayBufferLayer?.flush()
    displayBufferLayer?.stopRequestingMediaData()
    displayBufferLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

    let bufferLayer = AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer()
    bufferLayer.frame = view.bounds
    bufferLayer.videoGravity = videoGravity // (i.e. .resizeAspectFill)
    bufferLayer.isOpaque = true
    view.layer.insertSublayer(bufferLayer, at: 0)

    self.displayBufferLayer = bufferLayer
}
```